# BitmapFactory output bitmap created is null

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am downloading image from server, 
I am getting all the bytes but I am unable to get the bitmap using BitmapFactory.

Here is my code where ImageRetriever is fetching bytes from the server

```
ImageRetriver image = new ImageRetriver();  

byte[] byt = image.getProfileImage();               
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byt);

//Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
Bitmap bmp =(Bitmap) BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byt, 0, byt.length);
image1.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6520745/1012284

Comment: first you can check whether the bytes data is valid.Save the data to a file on sdcard,try to use IrfanView to open it.