# Render Byte Array on SurfaceView of android

Tags: android, arrays, surfaceview, android-canvas, surfaceholder

Hi  I have a raw dump of  image  which i  store as  byte  array  i have to  display this on surface view. I  tried to convert  this  byte  array  into a mutable  bitmap and  render on the  canvas of  surface holder  but  i get   this  null pointer exception when "drawBitmap"  function is called.

> BlockquoteE/AndroidRuntime(28358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1025)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28358):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1065)
>   Blockquote

This is  how i  try to  render the  byte array

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              //getting byte array
              byte[] bytes;
    File f1= new File("/data/dump.txt");
    int offset = 0, n = 0;
    InputStream in;
    long length = f1.length();
    bytes = new byte[(int) length];

          try {

          in = new FileInputStream(f1);

           while (offset < bytes.length
                && (n = in.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset))  >= 0) {
            offset += n;

           }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


              // getting byte array
                Bitmap bmp;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inMutable = true;
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length,options );
              Canvas  canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if(canvas != null){

                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null); 

              }
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); //finalize          

        }
```

Comment: Apart from the fact that you're missing a semicolon in line `byte[] bytes`, `bytes` doesn't seem to be instantiated anywhere. Have you skipped some code in your `surfaceCreated` function?

Comment: hi nadir  yes  i actually i clipped  some  code  where i read byte srray from sockets and store, as i didnt think it was  causing  any trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your byte array `bytes` is never instantiated. So, when you call `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray`, it returns `null`.

From the [Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29):

> *public static Bitmap decodeByteArray (byte[] data, int offset, int length, BitmapFactory.Options opts)*
>
> **Since: API Level 1**
>   Decode an immutable bitmap from the specified byte array.
>   ...
>
> **Returns**
>   The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)

Comment: i checked bmp file  is  always null added a  null check and  crash stops but i cant render on surfaceview.

Comment: @amITsingh is `"/data/dump.txt"` a valid format dump? I think it's not going to work if it's not a valid encoded byte array. Try checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null) and see if it helps

Comment: nadir  as i mentioned  its a  raw   rgb 888   format dump.. is this  a valid format  to be decoded into bitmap  or  only  jpeg  and png  valid  formats  ?

Comment: @amITsingh the valid formats are defined by BitmapFactoryOptions.[inPreferredConfig](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPreferredConfig). [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html#ARGB_8888) are the possible values (you should probably use ARGB_8888, add the alpha layer to your bytearray, then it should work correctly).

Comment: yes i added  the  pixel format to make it work  , correct me  if i am wrong  i should use ARGBX_888  if i  want to  ignore the alpha  channels

Comment: @amITsingh where did you find about `ARGBX_888`? I haven't found this format anywhere.

Comment: its  part of  android  pixel format  class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PixelFormat.html#RGBX_8888

Comment: ah, you meant `RGBX_8888` (not `ARGBX_888`). Anyway, it seems that `inPreferredConfig` are settings for the output. The android documentation are not informative at all about the format of byte array parameter, they just define it as `byte array of compressed image data`. So it seems you need to use a compression format (maybe YUV, who knows). The only advice I can give you is try first to use an `ARGB_8888` array instead of `RGB_888`. If it doesn't work, I'm sorry but I cannot help you any more.

Comment: Thanks , ARGB_8888 works  i am  able to render the  raw dump on surfaceview, why i wanted to to  know about RGBX_8888 is  because my raw dump aplha  channels  are messy  and i  dont want to use them. RGBX_8888 works  too and  to naked  eye i cant  any difference  so i was wondering .