# Bitmap giving null when I decode?

Tags: android, bitmap, arrays, bitmapfactory

```
byte[] imageInByte;
ImageView iViewAddImage;

if (imageInByte.length>0) {
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageInByte, 0, imageInByte.length);
   iViewAddImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
 }
```

I am getting the `Bitmap` value `null`  and  `imageInByte.length=20621`.

What am doing wrong. Sugesst me ?

EDIT 1 :

```
public void insertImage(byte[] imageInByte2) 
{
    if(sqliteDb != null)
    {
        try {
             sqliteDb.insert("database",null,getDataValues(imageInByte2));
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}

   private ContentValues getDataValues(byte[] imageInByte2){
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    try {
        contentValues.put("image",imageInByte2);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return contentValues;
  }
```

Comment: Where you have added the bytes of image in your byte array ? Try out `byte[] imageInByte=new byte[1024];`

Comment: see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null

Comment: You need to convert the image into the byte array then only add it for decoding.

Comment: I have added byte array into databse and reterive it from there ... @GrIsHu

Comment: can u post code how to generate byte array before store in database

Comment: the byte array you were retrieving is valid image bytes ? or raw bytes ?
or may be you need bitmap header to complete it ?

Comment: I have added the code snippet , how to store into database . @tsp

Answer (score 0):

this might help you

```
byte imageinbyte[];
bitmap bmp;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                imageInByte = bos.toByteArray();
```

You can directly set image view background

```
ImageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);|
```