# Problems with NativeDecodeByteArray in Android Bitmap.class

Tags: java, android, base64

I am decoding base 64 encoded images on Android(Java). It works for most of the images, but for some of the image binaries it returns null. If I use an online decoder, the binary in question works fine, which tells me the format is correct.

The piece of code on the Base64.class file that messes up is

```
if (!decoder.process(input, offset, len, true)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("bad base-64");
}

// Maybe we got lucky and allocated exactly enough output space.
if (decoder.op == decoder.output.length) {
    return decoder.output;
}

// Need to shorten the array, so allocate a new one of the
// right size and copy.
byte[] temp = new byte[decoder.op];
System.arraycopy(decoder.output, 0, temp, 0, decoder.op);
return temp;
```

For the images that fail, it goes through the

> maybe we got lucky check, and returns decoder.output and directly
>   jumps to return temp, which inturn returns null

. But for the images that work it does not enter that if and returns a non null temp variable. Is there a known issue with this?

**UPDATE**

Invoking code

```
 //This decodedString is null
    byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(
                        data, Base64.DEFAULT);
                Bitmap setBMPPath = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                        decodedString.length);

                qImage.setImageBitmap(setBMPPath);
```

**EDIT**

Turns out that the method is returning a value. Thanks @DavidEhrmann for the help. 
The error is actually in the next step where I am converting the decodestring into a bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap decodeByteArray(byte[] data, int offset, int length, Options opts) {
        if ((offset | length) < 0 || data.length < offset + length) {
            throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }
        Bitmap bm = nativeDecodeByteArray(data, offset, length, opts);
        if (bm == null && opts != null && opts.inBitmap != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Problem decoding into existing bitmap");
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

Here bm is returning null! Basically this call

```
Bitmap bm = nativeDecodeByteArray(data, offset, length, opts);
```

is null but since `opts != null && opts.inBitmap != null` are not true it does not throw the `IllegalArgumentException` and just returns bm as null. Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

I see an error in the log which says `Skia --decoder decode returns false`. I've tried every answer to every such question on SO and its still not working .

My Base64 code: http://pastebin.com/pnbqqg97

If its posted on a website that decodes online, it spits out the right image, but the bitmap  decoder fails.

**UPDATE - SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM**

As it turns out, the binary encoding was being done on a PNG file, and then being reconverted back into a bmp file, bmp to bmp seems to work in all cases. But I am surprises some png's converted also work!  BUt for me having the original image as a bmp is a problem because of the size, is there a way I can decode a PNG base 64 in Android reliably without using the BitMap factory>?

**ANSWER**

Turns out the image was actually invalid at one character point :O But it for some reason wasnt picked up by the online decoder but was in the code shown above.
 Make sure you check the code to see that you are not replacing any of the image base64 characters. Even one off can set it to go haywire as I found out

Comment: Do you mean android.util.Base64?

Comment: You are right, its with the util.base64 class, im debugging through it, and it fails where I mention it does.

Comment: It might be a padding issue. Is your input correctly padded with equal signs?

Comment: Seems to be, basically I tried to decode it online, it worked. It just seems to fail here

Comment: Care to paste it? It's possible to write a decoder that ignores them entirely.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pnbqqg97

Comment: 6016 chars, so no padding needed...

Comment: Yes, but It returns null for some reason, anything codewise that I need to change?

Comment: So basically, after I get the decoded string I convert it to an image, but the returned string is null

Comment: How are you invoking decode?

Comment: Everything looks fine. Except that you get back null. That's not actually possible with the above code. ```.length``` guarantees it won't be null, there.

Comment: I know right, It goes to return decoder.output;. It then jumps to return temp for some reason which is null and that is the value returned. Only a certain number of such strings it fails for, the rest it returns fine. And when it fails, decoder.op == decoder.output.length

Comment: It works as expected for me in Eclipse when I copy-and-pasted the source of Base64. All I can think of, now, is duplicating the class source in another package, see if that fixes it. The steps after that are look for compiler or VM bugs. And do a sanity check and make sure the checksum of data matches what you expect it to be.

Comment: Quick observation: some debuggers make you walk over the entire statement before seeing the result of the statement (an assignment, here), so it could have stopped on ```data, Base64.DEFAULT);``` before having actually made the call.

Comment: Did it work for you with the string I provided? Did it return a non null value?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Updated my question, you were right all along, its a different issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Why does BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray return null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null). What's a bit strange is that data you pastebinned looks like a valid PNG.

Comment: Exactly, still havent figured out why. Basically as per documentation it is null when the underlying image is not valid, but it is valid in my case. Ugh.

Comment: Run a CRC32/SHA1/whatever on the byte[] you get back and compare it to your source data (as a sanity check). Also, reencode you're PNG with something known to produce good PNGs. Maybe it got subtlety truncated.

Comment: Turns out the image was actually invalid at one character point :O But it for some reason wasnt picked up by the online decoder but was in the code shown above