# can not show image from byte array

Tags: android

in my app I am getting the `byte[]` from server and I need to show it on `imageview`
so I wrote this code:

```
byte[] im = allUsers.get(i).getPhoto().getBytes();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(im, 0, im.length);
((ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But `bmp` is always `null`. So what can be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to tell with out the rest of your code.  It is possible the bytes coming from the server are not complete or corrupted.  It is also possible you made an issue while loading the bytes.

Comment: That's way too broad, you need to make sure the byte array is actually containing the image first, also take a look at the logs in case it returns some sort of message of what went wrong with decoding the byte array...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null

Comment: Solved there was a problem with coming byte array