# decodeByteArray value returns null

Tags: android, json, base64

I am struggling with an issue in android that I need to parse byte array value which comes from JSON and show it on android device.For that I have written this

```
String base64Str = jsonObject.getString("dealimage");
   byte[] byteArray =  Base64.decode(base64Str.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
   Bitmap bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp1);
```

here bmp1 returns null value.can you please tell me why its returning null and solution.

Comment: this post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null

Comment: Why do you think it would? Found nothing relevant there. Which reply?