# Android - BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray return null

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory, android-camera2

I'm trying to do a camera application with image processing.
Here I tried to convert the image (byte array) to bitmap, but

```
BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
```

is returning null everytime

this is my code :

```
        Log.e("test -> arry byte = ", String.valueOf(byteArray));
        Log.e("byteArray.length = ", String.valueOf(byteArray.length));
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        Log.e("bitmap ici ->>> ", String.valueOf(bmp));
```

and the following stack trace :

[image]

Anyone has an idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray return null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520745/why-does-bitmapfactory-decodebytearray-return-null)

Comment: Can you post your code showing how you get the byte array? In all likelihood it is not a valid image.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/image.jpg");
ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, blob);
byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
```

//if bitmapdata is the byte array then getting bitmap goes like this

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata , 0, bitmapdata .length);
```